# JQuery, get all data attributes from a DOM Element

Tags: jquery

I have a select with several data attributes...

```
<option data-content="news" data-type="list">News List</option>
```

Is there a way to get all the data-attributes in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Call [**data**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) with no parameters

```js
var dataObject = $('option').data();
console.log(dataObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<option data-content="news" data-type="list">News List</option>
```